# Undefined constant "DRUPAL_ROOT" In civicrm.settings.php when running cv api job.execute

Tags: drupal, cron, cv

I'm trying to run cron with cv and I get this error. The site itself loads fine.

```
$ cv api job.execute --user=admin

In civicrm.settings.php line 97:
                                    
  Undefined constant "DRUPAL_ROOT"  
                                    

api3 [--in IN] [--out OUT] [--flat [FLAT]] [-T|--out=table] [-I|--out=list] [--level LEVEL] [--hostname HOSTNAME] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER] [--] <Entity.action> [<key=value>...]
```

Line 97 is

```
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.files']['path'] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/files/civicrm';
```

Why would cv not has access to the DRUPAL_ROOT constant? We're on Drupal 10.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with cv that that file is parsed before cms bootstrap.

But in any case I would just replace that line with the full path. In a normal install it just puts in the full path for that line.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what's happening. The problem is the dir are different on my local env vs my host so having it dynamic to the env is useful.

Comment: There are a couple ways to handle. One is change to the line to be `include '/path/outside/the/tree/civicrm.settings.local.php';` and put your local settings in there. Then the main civicrm.settings.php are identical. Another is use environment variables and read them in civicrm.setting.php, like `defined('DRUPAL_ROOT') ? DRUPAL_ROOT : getenv('LOCAL_DRUPAL_ROOT');`